# KeyCloak and passportjs-saml - Unable to complete SAML flow

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml, keycloak

I am using passport-saml to connect to a keycloak instance. I've tried other libs and they work fine with keycloak. With passport-saml I am able to get the login UI on keycloak but upon inputting the correct user/pass I'm getting:

```
Unexpected error when handling authentication request to identity provider.
```

The corresponding log from Keycloak:

```
04:28:12,309 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-121) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=test, clientId=passport-saml, userId=61ce9e95-b9cb-4555-8d16-a1b31bab643b, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=saml, redirect_uri=http://localhost:4000/assert, consent=no_consent_required, code_id=dbba7144-2a23-408c-b84b-dd46c2994d66, username=testuser
```

I am completely sure the user/pass is correct (works with other libs)

I tested passport-saml with OneLogin and it works there too, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
const s = (new SamlStrategy(
  {
    path: '/assert',
    host: 'localhost:4000',
    entryPoint: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/saml',
    issuer: 'passport-saml',
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./config/no-header-keycloak.crt', 'utf-8')
  },
  function(profile, done) {
    done(null, { username: 'test' });
  })
);
```

The generated SP metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="passport-saml" ID="passport_saml">
  <SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
    <AssertionConsumerService index="1" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:4000/assert"/>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

I can't make heads or tails of the keycloak error, so don't even know what to fix. If someone could point me in the correct direction that would be very helpful. Can share keycloak config as well, if required.